# How to plot several vectors qith quiver3 in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matlab-guide

Im trying to plot the elements of a given matrix

```
A = [ 1 2 3; 3 4 5, 5 6 7];
```

using quiver3, so all of these are in the same figure using:

```
figure(3);
hold on;
quiver3(0,0,0,A(1,1),A(1,2),A(1,3),0);
quiver3(0,0,0,A(2,1),A(2,2),A(2,3),0);
quiver3(0,0,0,A(3,1),A(3,2),A(3,3),0);
```

with the next result
[image]

instead of something like this
[image]

How can tell to quiver3 that plots all the vectors at the same time, or is there anyother command that can do this?

Comment: Everything's fine with your code! Have a look at [`view`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html). Running your code, and afterwards typing `[caz, cel] = view`, you'll get `caz = 0`, and `cel =  90`, thus the "2D view". Just set, for example,  `view(45, 45)` for a "3D view".

Comment: Thats right!, thanks!!